# UIView in front of everything not rotating with screen?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, rotation

I have this code:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    [app addSubViewOnFrontWindow:imageView];
```

...

```
- (void)addSubViewOnFrontWindow:(UIView *)view {
    int count = [self.windows count];
    UIWindow *w = [self.windows objectAtIndex:count - 1];
    [w addSubview:view];
}
```

The problem is, when the app rotates, the view on the front doesn't rotate. It just stays in portrait.

How can I get this to rotate normally with the rest of the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but `UIWindow` has a property [`rootViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html)

> The root view controller for the window.
>
> `@property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *rootViewController`
>
> **Discussion**
>   The root view controller provides the content view of the
>   window. Assigning a view controller to this property (either
>   programmatically or using Interface Builder) installs the view
>   controller’s view as the content view of the window. If the window has
>   an existing view hierarchy, the old views are removed before the new
>   ones are installed.
>
> The default value of this property is nil.
>
> **Availability**
>   Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>
> **Declared In**
>   UIWindow.h

As you should be providing this root view controller you should be able to add it to the rootViewContoller's view, and handle aout rotation correctly.

---

another solution could be, that you swap the windo with a custom one while presenting your view, with another view controller. this trick in action you can see in the implementation of [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView/blob/master/TSAlertView/TSAlertView.m).

```
- (void) show
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate date]];

    TSAlertViewController* avc = [[[TSAlertViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    avc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // $important - the window is released only when the user clicks an alert view button
    TSAlertOverlayWindow* ow = [[TSAlertOverlayWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    ow.alpha = 0.0;
    ow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    ow.rootViewController = avc;
    [ow makeKeyAndVisible];

    // fade in the window
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.2 animations: ^{
        ow.alpha = 1;
    }];

    // add and pulse the alertview
    // add the alertview
    [avc.view addSubview: self];
    [self sizeToFit];
    self.center = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX( avc.view.bounds ), CGRectGetMidY( avc.view.bounds ) );;
    self.frame = CGRectIntegral( self.frame );
    [self pulse];

    if ( self.style == TSAlertViewStyleInput )
    {
        [self layoutSubviews];
        [self.inputTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

with

```
@interface TSAlertOverlayWindow : UIWindow
{
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIWindow* oldKeyWindow;
@end

@implementation  TSAlertOverlayWindow
@synthesize oldKeyWindow;

- (void) makeKeyAndVisible
{
    self.oldKeyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    self.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
    [super makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void) resignKeyWindow
{
    [super resignKeyWindow];
    [self.oldKeyWindow makeKeyWindow];
}

//

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

add a new window, with new rootviewController, and subscribe it to

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:(id) selector:(SEL) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows don't autorotate. Ever. You should be adding this imageView to a UIViewController's view as the UIViewController has built in autorotation.

If you want to use a UIWindow to hold all your views, you will need to write your own transform code to handle rotations.

Comment: So how Can i put a UIView in front of everything with it still able to rotate? I want it to display in front of the keyboard.

Comment: You can try `[imageview.super bringSubviewToFront:imageview]`, but that is a long shot. I'd be surprised if it worked (because the keyboard probably isn't on the same view), but worth a try.